# how to add audio to all html pages

Tags: html, session, audio, asp-classic, audio-player

**i need an option to stop the music in a player on one page and make sure it won't run it on the next one.**

i successfully added music using  audio tag to each page but whenever i go to another page the file is reopen again.
i found no answer how to do it

**beside open pop up - but that not the best way**

i tried to isolate the audio and putted it a separate asp file to get session whenever music on or off (run the asp from an iframe from each html pages).

```
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html"; charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<%
Session("music")=Request("b1")
if Session("music")="" then 

%>
<form method="post" action="music.asp">
<button onclick="display()" type="radio" name="b1"   class="ato2"  style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;width: 50px;  height: 50px;background-image: url('withsound.png');   background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 45px 45px;  " value="off"></button>


  <audio id="myplayer" autoplay="true" controls="false" loop="true" hidden="hidden" mediagroup="AnyName" autobuffer>
  <source src="music/enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" >
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> 
</form>
<%
elseif Session("music")  = "off" then 

%>
<form method="post" action="music.asp">
<button onclick="display()" type="radio" name="b1"   class="ato2"  style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;width: 50px;  height: 50px;background-image: url('nosound.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 45px 45px; " value=""></button>


</form>
<%
end if
Session("music")=Request("b1")
response.write "<br>"
response.write "music:" & Session("music")

%>
</body>
</html>
```

it was suppose to be simple session transfer but it didn't succeeded.

i found the asnwer i were looking for

> The Application Object
>   it's exactly what i needed in order to save information to the next page
>   so now i know whenever user switch music of or on

Comment: Remind me to never ever visit the website you're working on. :/

Comment: What Martha means is that playing audio continuously on your site is extremely bad form. There are certain things on the web that should always be opt in!

Comment: Martha bekieve me i wouldn't like you to go to my website either :)

Comment: Paul maybe i explained myself not so but what i trying to create is same music on every page with option to mute it or continue from every page. how to i don't know, i don't want to think that creating it in pop up is best solution and that's why i am writing here.

Comment: Just to elaborate on my somewhat snide remark: a site should ***NEVER EVER UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES*** play background music. Foreground music, i.e. where the user presses "play" on something they want to hear, is fine. Foreground music that the user then minimizes/sends to the background (e.g. an internet radio station) is fine. But a random website that has nothing to do with music DOES NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO USE MY SPEAKERS. The sorts of sites that break this law are the sorts of sites that I don't give my business to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not want to handle audio on the server side, other than something simple maybe like storing a cookie and determining if the audio should auto play or not.

The problem is, when you are using audio on background music, is the page refresh.  Each time the page refreshes, the audio will stop, and then play again.

Few options:

1. You could frameset the whole site, and then have the main frame play the audio.  The disadvantages of frames is pretty well known.  They can create a nightmare for design and even more for SEO
2. You can open a pop up window, but that is very ugly
3. You can build your site using modern AJAX type technology where the whole page does not refresh.   This would be turning your site into an SPA

If you dont mind the music starting / stopping each time the user navigates from page to page, or if you are just using audio for alerts & beebs to get the user's attention then you best bet is store each user's audio prefences in a cookie, and then log those settings to the USER DB if the user is logged in.

Comment: i will try , but is there a way to open new window as an invisible? or should i open new tab? can i auto open new tab?

Comment: You cannot open a new window in invisible since the old MSIE 6 days where you could pop up a window under the current one.   Most browsers now will just force it to be on top.   It would be a nasty way to try and get background music on your site anyways, because the child window would remain open if the parent is closed.